# How to track auto-generated id's in select-insert statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have two tables detail and head.  The detail table will be written first.  Later, the head table will be written.  The head is a summary of the detail table.  I would like to keep a reference from the detail to the head table.  I have a solution but it is not elegant and requires duplicating the joins and filters that were used during summation.  I am looking for a better solution.  The below is an example of what I currently have.  In this example, I have simplified the table structure.  In the real world, the summation is very complex.

```
-- Preparation
create table #detail (
      detail_id int identity(1,1)
    , code char(4)
    , amount money 
    , head_id int null
    );

create table #head (
      head_id int identity(1,1)
    , code char(4)
    , subtotal money
    );

insert into #detail ( code, amount ) values ( 'A', 5 );
insert into #detail ( code, amount ) values ( 'A', 5 );
insert into #detail ( code, amount ) values ( 'B', 2 );
insert into #detail ( code, amount ) values ( 'B', 2 );


-- I would like to somehow simplify the following two queries
insert into #head ( code, subtotal )
    select code, sum(amount)
    from #detail
    group by code

update #detail 
  set head_id = h.head_id
from #detail d
  inner join #head h on d.code = h.code

-- This is the desired end result
select * from #detail
```

Desired end result of detail table:

```
  detail_id  code  amount  head_id
  1          A     5.00    1
  2          A     5.00    1
  3          B     2.00    2
  4          B     2.00    2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your subject I would say this.

Have you seen the [OUTPUT clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)?

It will let you assign your ID's to variables so you won't need the temp tables.

But from your body, I don't really understand what you're doing...

Comment: This might be a possibility.  I will look into this.  Thanks!

Comment: I rewrote the query using the OUTPUT clause and it is much cleaner.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Why not just insert the `head` rows first, and then join to head when inserting the `detail` rows? In other words, if you know the distinct codes you are going to be using for the detail records (A and B in your example), you can go ahead and insert them into the `head` table. Then, you can just insert the `detail` records afterward, joining to head to get the `head_id` value for the corresponding code.

Comment: The process that generates the detail records is seperate from the process that generates the head records, but thanks for the suggestion.